# IIS Application pool could not create Windows user token from credentials specified in the config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am running into this error on one IIS host, but not on another IIS host.  The Application Pool on both IIS are configured the same way and use the ApplicationPoolIdentity. The App Pool that has the error has the "Enable 32-BitApplications" property set to false while the property in the other IIS is set to true. The Windows Server Application Log has the following warning:

```html
Event time (UTC): 1/10/2017 9:01:04 PM 
Event ID: 7bf7aa022bc742228e4618bb0f156496 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT/CMT-12-131285556603923859 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /MyApp 
    Application Path: E:\Staging\MyApp\ 
    Machine name: WebServerName 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 3048 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Staging 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for system.web/identity.
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)

Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is incorrect.
' (E:\Staging\myApp\web.config line 144)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the posting.  I overlooked the credential in the web.config.  It's resolved.